# Webpack make jQuery globally available during development

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm writing a react app that will live inside of a webpage that already contains jquery. This means I need global access to jQuery during development, but do not want to include it with the bundle on build ( since jquery will already exist on the page where it is deployed ).

I'm having difficulty getting jquery as a global ( aka accessible from anywhere via `$` or `window.jquery`) to work. Specifically I need jQuery@1.7.2. Here is what I've done so far:

```
npm install jquery@1.7.2
```

then, in webpack.dev.config.js:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
  })
]
```

...however, when I run my dev server (`webpack-dev-server`) and try to use jQuery in a module, I get:

```
error '$' is not defined
```

Any ideas? my main goals are:

1. should be present during development build, but not bundled for production
2. should be globally accessible from any component via the window object
3. not have to explicitly be imported into each module ( assume it's a global )

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `webpack.dev.config.js` in dev mode?

Comment: @MitchKarajohn I am. I'm wondering if it's due to the version jquery I am using? ( 1.7.2 opposed to 2.x or 3.x ). this version is a req though.

Comment: Hm, apparently [that version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) exposes the `jQuery` object to the window by default (`/* Expose jQuery to the global object*/ window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;`). Maybe you don't need to use the `ProvidePlugin` at all, just make sure you load the library before the rest of your code. Try this and post results

Comment: @MitchKarajohn doesn't appear so... if I do `import $ from 'jquery'` in the root module, I still get error `$ is not defined` in the components

Comment: Don't do `import $ from 'jquery'`. It does not return anything. Simply execute it: `import 'jquery'`

Comment: doesn't seem to work no matter how I import it.. just says it's not defined. Should I be doing this inside of webpack, or inside my source code? I tried `import 'jquery'` in my app entry point, and use `$` inside the child components, but it's not defined.

Comment: Ok, give me a couple of minutes to try this in an example project and I'll get back to you

Comment: Just an FYI I am getting this nice warning when installing jQuery v1.7.2: `npm WARN deprecated jquery@1.7.2: Versions of the jquery npm package older than 1.9.0 are patched versions that don't work in web browsers. Please upgrade to >=1.11.0.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time on this, here are my observations:

- Installing `jquery@1.7.2`, throws the following warning: 
  `npm WARN deprecated jquery@1.7.2: Versions of the jquery npm package older than 1.9.0 are patched versions that don't work in web browsers. Please upgrade to >=1.11.0.`.
- Trying to build my bundles using this version of `jquery` completely fails. I don't know how you did it, but for me it fails. I am using `webpack@1.13.3`
- I checked the source code of the `jquery` downloaded with `npm install jquery@1.7.2`. It is definitely modified from the [original source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js). The original source code still exists though under `jquery/tmp/jquery.js`

**Conclusion**

Your best bet for this to work is by doing this, at some point before the rest of your code:

`import 'jquery/tmp/jquery'`.

This way the file will be executed, `jquery` will be registered to `window`, as originally intended, and you can use `$` in the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. This did the trick for me. Thanks for your help!